# Match a basic csv-pattern with a regex

Tags: regex, csv

I am having difficulty matching the following csv-type output with a regex. For example, with:

```
Ten Thousand,10000
Ten thousand
helloasdf,x
```

I thought perhaps I could use the basic:

```
# start at either the start-of-line or a comma
(^|,)
# consume up through a comma (though end-of-line will not have that
[^,]*
# go until the next comma or end of line
($|,)
```

Yet this doesn't work, even if I wrap it in a group and try and repeat it. What is it that I'm doing wrong here? Link here: https://regex101.com/r/AmzZ8n/1

Comment: What are you trying to match? The terms? If so, try `[^,]+` and the entire match will be each term - ie group `0`

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58773990/372239) and add sample text and **expected result**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex I used is:

```
(?:^|,)([^,]*)
```

1. `(?:^|,)` A non-capturing group that matches either the start of the line or a `,`.
2. `([^,]*)` A capturing group that matches 0 or more non-comma characters. This allows for empty columns.

I have added some additional test case. The one problematic one may be the last one:

`',d,e'`

There is a bug in the regex engine prior to Python 3.7 in handling 0-length matches in certain cases. You may need to install the `regex` package at https://pypi.org/project/regex/ from the `PYPI` repository and then:

`import regex as re`

The code:

```
import re

lines = [
    'Ten Thousand,10000',
    'Ten thousand',
    'helloasdf,x',
    'a,b,,c,',
    ',d,e'
]

regex = re.compile('(?:^|,)([^,]*)')
for line in lines:
    print(regex.findall(line))
```

Prints:

```
['Ten Thousand', '10000']
['Ten thousand']
['helloasdf', 'x']
['a', 'b', '', 'c', '']
['', 'd', 'e']
```

[Run Demo](https://ideone.com/e0C1Tk)